Type-check an array of tuples
I'm trying to write and type-check an array of tuples that pair an action creator with its reducer, and need to validate:

That the action's Payload is the same as the reducer's Payload
That all the reducers accept the same State

The idea is to write it in a way that is library agnostic, and without having to maintain a list of valid payloads.
type A = string;
type B = number;
type State = { a: A; b: B };
type Action<Payload> = { type: string; payload: Payload };
type ActionFn<Payload> = (payload: Payload) => Action<Payload>;

const actionA: ActionFn<A> = (payload: A) => ({ type: 'A', payload });
const actionB: ActionFn<B> = (payload: B) => ({ type: 'B', payload });

const reducerA = (state: State, a: A): State => ({ ...state, a });
const reducerB = (state: State, b: B): State => ({ ...state, b });


type ActionReducerPair<State, Payload> = [
  ActionFn<Payload>,
  (state: State, payload: Payload) => State
];

type Reducer<State, Payload> = (state: State, payload: Payload) => State;

const reducers = [
  // These are OK
  [actionA, reducerA],
  [actionB, reducerB],

  // These should report an error
  // @ts-expect-error
  [actionB, reducerA],
  // @ts-expect-error
  [actionA, reducerB],
];

TypeScript Playground

My attempts
So it's clear to me that I need a generic context for each entry. I've tried:

Calling a function for each entry in order
This works, however I would prefer to express the solution using only a data structure.
type Pair<State, Payload> = [
  ActionFn<Payload>,
  (state: State, payload: Payload) => State
];
const pair = <State, Payload>(
  actionCreator: ActionFn<Payload>,
  reducerFn: (state: State, payload: Payload) => State
): Pair<State, Payload> => [actionCreator, reducerFn];

const reducerPairs2 = [
  // These are OK
  pair(actionA, reducerA), // ✅
  pair(actionB, reducerB), // ✅

  // These should report an error
  // @ts-expect-error
  pair(actionB, reducerA), // ✅
  // @ts-expect-error
  pair(actionA, reducerB), // ✅
];


Enforcing the type with a type helper
This doesn't quite work, either it passes all or it fails all.
type ValidPair<MaybeAction, MaybeReducer> = 
  MaybeAction extends ActionFn<infer Payload>
    ? MaybeReducer extends Reducer<infer State, Payload>
      ? ActionReducerPair<State, Payload>
      : 'reducer does not satisfy Reducer<S, P>'
    : 'action does not satisfy ActionFn<P>';

const reducers = [
  // These are OK
  [actionA, reducerA], // ✅
  [actionB, reducerB], // ✅

  // These should give an error
  // @ts-expect-error //  no error reported
  [actionB, reducerA],
  // @ts-expect-error //  no error reported
  [actionA, reducerB],
] satisfies Array<ValidPair<ActionFn<any>, Reducer<State, any>>>;




You can actually do that with the types you have already defined. Use your type ActionReducerPair in a union (ActionReducerPair<State, A> | ActionReducerPair<State, B>)[] to define all valid pairs.
type A = string;
type B = number;
type State = { a: A; b: B };
type Action<Payload> = { type: string; payload: Payload };
type ActionFn<Payload> = (payload: Payload) => Action<Payload>;

const actionA: ActionFn<A> = (payload: A) => ({ type: "A", payload });
const actionB: ActionFn<B> = (payload: B) => ({ type: "B", payload });

const reducerA = (state: State, a: A): State => ({ ...state, a });
const reducerB = (state: State, b: B): State => ({ ...state, b });

type ActionReducerPair<State, Payload> = [
  ActionFn<Payload>,
  (state: State, payload: Payload) => State,
];

const reducers: (ActionReducerPair<State, A> | ActionReducerPair<State, B>)[] =
  [
    [actionA, reducerA], // okay
    [actionB, reducerB], // okay
    [actionB, reducerA], // error!
    [actionA, reducerB], // error!
  ];

TypeScript Playground

Maintaining the union of valid combinations would be cumbersome, any individual list of reducers can quickly reach 20, and across the project there's 1k and growing.

Conditional Types
I would solve this with a distributive conditional type on the array:
type Reducer<State, Payload> = (state: State, payload: Payload) => State;

const reducerA: Reducer<State, A> = (state: State, a: A): State => ({ ...state, a });
const reducerB: Reducer<State, B> = (state: State, b: B): State => ({ ...state, b });

type ActionReducerPair<State, Payload> = [
  ActionFn<Payload>,
  Reducer<State, Payload>
];

type PossiblePayloads = A | B;

type ReducerArray<State, T extends PossiblePayloads> = T extends PossiblePayloads ? ActionReducerPair<State, T>[] : never;

const reducers: ReducerArray<State, PossiblePayloads> = [
  // These are OK
  [actionA, reducerA],
  [actionB, reducerB],

  // These now give an error
  [actionB, reducerA],
  [actionA, reducerB],
];

Essentially, the ReducerArray type will allow typescript to check the Payload type to the corresponding ActionReducerPair type.
Evidently, this solution is only valid if you can maintain the ReducerArray type.
Edit: Changed code to use a distributive conditional type to simplify maintenance

This is neater than Behemoth's solution in that you only have a union of payloads, but I'd really prefer not to have to maintain a this union because we're looking at 1k reducer pairs and growing.

I've combined Behemoth's solution using a Union type with mine using conditional types to simplify maintenance. You won't be able to avoid maintaining some sort of type holding the possible payloads together.

The pair()-function in my attempt avoids this, but I suppose you're right that TS doesn't support this use-case well.
